# Angular2 how to add 3rd party plugin using AngularCLI (webpack)

Tags: angular, angular-cli, scrollmagic

I'm developing an Angular2 app using AngularCLI (webpack version).  I have a 3rd party plugin (ScrollMagic) that itself has its own set of optional plugins.  I've installed ScrollMagic codebase and it resides in node_modules.  I can load ScrollMagic into my page using the following syntax:

```
let ScrollMagic = require("ScrollMagic");
```

This appears to reach into node_modules and loads ScrollMagic and I can get the 3rd party plugin to work.

ScrollMagic has a it's own plugin (ScrollMagic/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js) used for debugging.  I'm having difficulty getting this plugin loaded.  I've tried the following:

```
require("ScrollMagic/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js");
```

and the plugin cannot be found.

I'm using AngularCLI so I tried adding debug.addIndicators.min.js to "scripts" section of angular-cli.json.  This loads debug.addIndicators.min.js into global space but ScrollMagic itself doesn't seem to recognize it (at this point, I'm still using let ScrollMagic = require("ScrollMagic"); to load ScrollMagic itself).

I then tried loading ScrollMagic proper in "scripts" section of angular-cli.json.  This loads SCrollMagic in global space, but then I have to remove 'let ScrollMagic = require("ScrollMagic")' from the codebase otherwise ScrollMagic gets loaded twice.  I set let ScrollMagic : any to make TypeScript not complain, but then ScrollMagic never gets instantiated correctly.

What am I missing here?  I can get ScrollMagic to work without the debugging tool, which is what I want for production, but I'm not able to debug it for development purposes.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.  This is what I did.

in the angular-cli.json  i added this into scripts:

```
      "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/gsap/src/minified/TweenMax.min.js",
    "../node_modules/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/minified/ScrollMagic.min.js",
    "../node_modules/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/minified/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js",
    "../node_modules/scrollmagic/scrollmagic/minified/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"
  ],
```

now when I write my components I just use scrollmagic like normal and I have indicators and scrolling events.